# bash: extract an attribute value between quotes using awk or sed(GNU grep is not an option)

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, aix

I have a xml file with data like below

```
<temp>
<a="something" total="50" b="something" total="0" c="something" total="20">
</temp>
```

I need to get first value of total i.e, 50 but my sed solution is giving value of last occurrence of total i.e, 20

```
sed -n 's/.*total="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' temp.xml
```

output : 20

desired output: 50

I appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Isn't it wrong to have three attributes with the same name?

Comment: greedy match will eat up until the last "total"

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using XML-aware tools? `//a/@total` will extract your `50` in any XPath processor. (XMLStarlet, non-ancient xmllint, etc).

Comment: ...though this isn't actually valid XML with `<a="something"`, I'm assuming that was bad summarization.

Comment: example I have given is not a valid xml. xml aware tools are NOT installed on our aix server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` does not support non greedy match. Excerpt from [here](http://0x2a.at/blog/2008/07/sed--non-greedy-matching/):

> The trick to get non greedy matching in sed is to match all characters excluding the one that terminates the match.

So your solution is becomes:

```
sed -n 's/.[^ ]* total="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' temp.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data file:

```
$ cat my.xml
<temp>
<a="something" total="50" b="something" total="0" c="something" total="20">
</temp>
```

And a quick `awk` solution based on the limited data sample and sole requirement of retrieving the **first** `total` value:

```
$ awk -F'"' '/ total=/ { print $4}' my.xml
50
```

- `-F'"'` : define (input) field separator as a double quote
- `/ total=/` : only interested in lines that include the string ' total=', and then ...
- `print $4` : print the 4th field

Comment: How is that retrieving the first `total` value, as opposed to just the first value on a line that contains the substring `total` anywhere in it?

Answer (score 1):

you should perhaps use a xml aware tool but grep can handle this with ease.

```
grep -Pom1 '(?<=total=")[^"]+' file | head -1
50
```

this finds all total attribute values on the first matched line and gets the first of them.

Lacking look behind regex feature, you can fall back to

```
$ grep -Eo 'total="[^"]+"' file | awk -F\" '{print $2; exit}'

50
```

Comment: OP said they can't rely on GNUisms in their `grep` implementation, which `-P` certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
cut -sd '"' -f 4 my.xml
```

Comment: This depends on the order of attributes -- if this is genuinely XML (and it certainly appears to be), that ordering isn't guaranteed to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

The following will print `total` attributes for all `a` elements in your file, one to a line:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//a[@total]' -v ./@total -n <your-file.xml
```

---

If you don't have XMLStarlet, you can do this with `xsltproc` (which is available almost everywhere). Given the following xslt file (generated as output of `xmlstarlet sel -C -t -m '//a[@total]' -v ./@total -n`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//a[@total]">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@total"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...you can run:

```
xsltproc extract-totals.xslt your-file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use xml/html parsers, like **`xmllint`** and/or **`xmlstarlet`**.

**`xmllint`** solution:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "string(//a/@total)" temp.xml 2>/dev/null
50
```